# Как убрать отступ сверху и снизу текста

Tags: css, html, style, текст

Как убрать отступ сверху и снизу текста? Изображение проблемы прилагаеться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Лучше добавте проблемный код.

Comment: Полагаю, вам нужен reset.css или normalize.css (гуглятся на раз).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи значения `line-height`.

Описание:

> Устанавливает интерлиньяж (межстрочный интервал) текста, отсчет
>   ведется от базовой линии шрифта. При обычных обстоятельствах
>   расстояние между строками зависит от вида и размера шрифта и
>   определяется браузером автоматически. Отрицательное значение
>   межстрочного расстояния не допускается.

Синтаксис:

```
line-height: множитель | значение | проценты | normal | inherit
```

Значения:

> Любое число больше нуля воспринимается как множитель от размера шрифта
>   текущего текста. Например, значение 1.5 устанавливает полуторный
>   межстрочный интервал. В качестве значений принимаются также любые
>   единицы длины, принятые в CSS — пикселы (px), дюймы (in), пункты (pt)
>   и др. Разрешается использовать процентную запись, в этом случае за
>   100% берется высота шрифта.
>
> `normal` Расстояние между строк вычисляется автоматически. `inherit`
>   Наследует значение родителя.

Подробнее [ТУТ](http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height)

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё таки убрать путём манипуляций `margin` и `padding`. Если отступы, допустим, от верха в контейнере ровны `50рх`, то поставте `47` и всё. Просто - 3рч +-2рх.

Comment: Но ведь отступы в примере по нулям (или я что-то просмотрел). А залазить в минуса как то не этично. Не на всем софте этот минус будет одинаково хорошо смотреться.